# Json fields getting sorted by default when converted to spark DataFrame

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**When I create a dataframe from json file, the fields from the json file are sorted by default in the dataframe. How to avoid this sorting?**
Jsonfile having one json message per line:

`{"name":"john","age":10,"class":2}
 {"name":"rambo","age":11,"class":3}`

When I create Data frame from this file as:
`val jDF = sqlContext.read.json("/user/inputfiles/sample.json")`

a DF is created as 
 `jDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: bigint, class: bigint, name: string]`
. In the DF the fields are sorted by default.
How do we avoid this from happening?

Im unable to understand what is going wrong here.

Appreciate any help in sorting out the problem.

Comment: Ask **one** question per question.

Comment: You're saying that the DF ends up with the properties in a different order from the JSON, but JSON objects are an **unordered** collection of fields; [reference](http://json.org). `{"a":1,"b":2}` and `{"b":2,"a":1}` are exactly the same thing. So there's no "order" in the JSON that DF has to pay any attention to. (Don't know anything about DF, so I don't know if those have order.)

Comment: Thanks for the response @T.J.Crowder. I have to create a table with column order in the same sequence as in the source json. So, the sorting of json properties in the dataframe is troubling me.

Comment: I understand. But again: JSON objects **have** no order. Even if you're getting them in a particular order in the JSON text *right now*, there's no guarantee that whatever is generating them won't suddenly change that order (even between minor releases of the JSON serializer it uses).  So the requirement you've been given makes no sense. You need to change the JSON feed to send you an array instead.

Answer (score 3):

For Question 1:

A simple way is to do `select` on the `DataFrame`:

```
val newDF = jDF.select("name","age","class")
```

The order of parameters is the order of the columns you want.

But this could be verbose if there are many columns and you have to define the order yourself.