# Flattening the array of a dataframe column into separate columns and corresponding values in Spark scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is my dataframe. Im getting this dataframe by converting the java Json list to dataframe.

```
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   |                              Value                                                              |
+---+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1| {"Name":"john","type":"On(r) TV: Channel","desc_lang":"en~en~en~en","copyright":"Copyright 2021"}|
|-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2| {"Name":"Dane","type":"On(r) TV: Prgrm","desc_lang":"FR~FR~FR~FR","copyright":"Copyright 2022"}  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The required output is as below.

```
+---+---------------------+---+-------+----------------+
|Name|    type            | desc_lang | copyright      |
+----+--------------------+-----------+-------+--------+
|john| On(r) TV: Channel  | en~en~en~en |Copyright 2021|
|Dane| On(r) TV: Prgrm    | FR~FR~FR~FR |Copyright 2022|
+----+--------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

This is only the sample data, I actually have around 180 columns that needs to be flattened to the above tabular format. Below is the code I  tried splitting, but it did not given me the desired output.

```
val dfcollect = DF.withColumn("finalop", split($"Value", ":"))
```

Could someone please assist on how to achieve this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `from_json` and star expand the resulting struct:

```
val df2 = df.select(
    from_json(
        col("Value"), 
        schema_of_json(df.select("Value").head().getString(0))
    ).as("Value")
).select("Value.*")

df2.show
+----+-------------+-----------+---------------+
|Name|    copyright|  desc_lang|           type|
+----+-------------+-----------+---------------+
|john|Copyright2021|en~en~en~en|On(r)TV:Channel|
|Dane|Copyright2022|FR~FR~FR~FR|  On(r)TV:Prgrm|
+----+-------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: `df.select("Value").head().getString(0)` what if first element is null or empty ?

Comment: @mck thanks for your reply. With the above code I am able to get the output,but the columns are not in order.It is actually giving the columns in alphabetical order. But I need the columns order as is from the dataframe. Could you please let me know how to get this.

Comment: A JSON object, by definition, is an unordered collection of fields (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922984/json-fields-getting-sorted-by-default-when-converted-to-spark-dataframe#comment63296148_37922984), for example). Why do you want the columns to maintain its original order?

Comment: After parsing, I want to load this data into a delta table,which has a predefined schema.So , I need the column order to be as the target schema.

Comment: then you can get the schema from the delta table and use `select` to rearrange the columns

Comment: Yes, that would work. But , the parsing code is generic to 3 different schemas.Is there any way I could get the column order as is from the dataframe whithout manually specifying the column names using select.

Comment: you don't need to manually specify the columns. You can get the schema from the destination and apply it to the current dataframe

Comment: And each schema has around 180+ coulmns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233275/discussion-between-sanjanasanju-and-mck).